# Show that $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt[] {3} \sin(\frac{\pi}{5})-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3}))$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

As in the title, I want to show that $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt[]{3} \sin(\frac{\pi}{5})-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3}))$ is normal.

My idea was the following: Let $\alpha:=i\sqrt[] {3} \sin(\frac{\pi}{5})-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})$, then we can write $\alpha=(2\zeta_3-1)\cdot\Im(\zeta_{10})+\frac{1}{2}$ and now I guess we have $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{30})$, the $30$th cyclotomic field of $\mathbb Q$. And, since the galois group of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{30})$ is abelian, we have that every subfield is normal over $\mathbb Q$. My problem: Is my assumption even true? And if so, how do I show it?

Comment: It is certainly contained in a cyclotomic field, and that is enough for your application. But I think you may have to use $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{60})$ rather than $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{30})$.

Comment: My problem is: What ensures that I get imaginary parts of the unit roots?

Comment: Wait: $\Im(\zeta_{10})=\frac{1}{2i}(\zeta_{10}-\zeta_{10}^{-1})$, so everything should be contained in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{30})$, right?

Comment: You have an $i$ there....

Comment: Yes, that's what I just realized as well. Dammit